# Invited for an Interview - But descrepancy in Address from Bank Statement (visa application)

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, business-travel, application-status

**Intro:**

I have been interviewing for an Engineering position with a company among the fortune 500+. After passing a series of rounds, they invited me over for a final onsite Interview in 2 weeks time, they sent a **tentative** Travel itinerary and a visa letter. (They are sponsoring the entire trip).

I have just made my visa application.

**Concerns:**

I am a fresh graduate with no "Strong Ties" to my home country, ("Strong Ties" - by definition and according all I have been reading here for the past 3 hours being:- "Single", "Orphaned", "Recently Graduated", "low paying Part-time job"). (to my disadvantage)

I am sure my Country is statistically on the **high side** of those who try to use deceptive means to obtain visa or stay longer than required. (to my disadvantage)

I was truthful while filling the form, however, **one of my bank** statements has a different address from my nominal home address used in all other documents. (my major concern)

The reason was because I opened it 3 years ago when I went for a paid internship program in a state ~1000km from my home state.

**Question:**

I am slated for my biometrics early next week. the bank cannot change my address for me in due time because the bureaucracy involved takes many days.

This is the first visa I've applied for. Considering the fact that I am implicitly at a disadvantage, Is the discrepancy in address an automatic disqualification?

My understanding is that the ECO's decision will be based on "evidences". Do I need further "evidence" to explain this discrepancy?

Comment: Prospective employer pays _business class_ tickets for a candidate to attend an interview? Sounds like a possible scam. Be extremely careful to verify that you're indeed talking to the company you think you're talking to, and bail and run at the first hint of paying anything out of pocket to a service provider that _you_ didn't choose yourself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, It was sent as a "Tentative Itinerary" so that I can obtain a visa... I don't believe the "Business class" thing either. Thank you, I've double checked the mail's authenticity...

Comment: Why did you not change the address on this account three years ago? How are the statements from this account reaching you if they are being sent to the wrong address?

Comment: @DJClayworth, I didn't change the address. I opened the account there. The statements have been, and are being delivered electronically by email

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about it if you have a good explanation. If you don't have any old bills that show the old address, then if you can pull your credit history, that will show all the addresses you've used and you could bring that to the interview.

Comment: You have already submitted your application and are now suffering from post-submission anxiety. The decision is up to the ECO and all we can offer you here is guesstimates. It appears you have taken care in preparing your application and given a glance at your SO profile I believe you might  indeed be a high-profile applicant to the company and the ECO will note that. For all I can tell they will not fail you on the address of a bank statement, at most they would follow up on it. Please take no personal offence in me voting to close this question as mostly opinion-based.

Comment: @mts nice one, voting to close as 'post-submission anxiety'.

Comment: Adding 'application-status' tag (it covers post-submission anxiety)

Comment: I would say don't worry too much particularly if your firm is well known and prestigious. Goldman Sachs in U.K. last year did similar for a few fresh graduates from Ghana. They got the visas. Of course Goldman Sachs is creme de la creme however the idea is that top young candidates have options and will likely be successful wherever they stay and won't want to go be illegal in U.K.